# How do you select the comments from a DB2 table?

Tags: db2

how do I query the table comments from a table in my DB2 database?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the *SYSCAT.TABLES* catalog view:

```
select remarks from syscat.tables where tabname = 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve comments (or "remarks") on objects in DB2, look in the catalog tables.  [The SYSCAT catalog tables for DB2 LUW](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011297.html) are different from the [SYSIBM catalog tables in DB2 z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_catalogtablesintro.html).

For LUW, the following commands will get table-level comments and column-level comments:

```sql
select tabname, tabschema, remarks from syscat.tables where tabname='TABLENAME'
select tabname, tabschema, colname, remarks from syscat.columns where tabname='TABLENAME'
```

For z/OS, use the following queries instead:

```sql
select name, creator, dbname, remarks from sysibm.systables where name='TABLENAME'
select name, tbcreator, tbname, remarks from sysibm.syscolumns where tbname='TABLENAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

select colname,remarks from syscat.columns where tabname='T1'

This will be useful for you.

Comment: the question was about table and the answer is already provided, your is variation of it for columns.